# Transferring data from android to PC via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, client-server, data-transfer

Anybody could give a working example of bluetooth server client(from android to Computer),which can transfer files or message from one end to other?I make it using TCP,but i can't successful with bluetooth for last 2 days.
I found some articles from Google,but i can't success with those.From [This](http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-simple-spp.html) tutorial i try for myself,but got exception in **onResume()** that connection failed.
I want to transfer data from my **android mobile to my PC** running windows 7.At now i work with below code which works good,because from logcat i see the connection is set successfully and read data perfectly,but still it don't transfer data to my computer(may be can't write those data).
So my question is,am i missing something or need such a code for server end?Or can anyone suggest some piece of code that should successfully **transfer a message or a file from client android to server PC**?
**MY code:**

```
Button btnSend = null;
TextView txtPath = null;
Socket s = null;
BluetoothAdapter objBluetoothAdapter = null;
BluetoothDevice device = null;
BluetoothSocket socket = null;
String strPath = "/sdcard/bluetooth/IMG0245A.jpg";
byte [] buffer = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String address="MY_COMPUTER_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS";

        objBluetoothAdapter =  BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(objBluetoothAdapter==null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "BT not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                return;
        }

        //objBluetoothAdapter.enable();

        if(!objBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivity(enableBT);
        }
        try{
                device = objBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

                final UUID uuid= UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

                try{
                        File f = new File(strPath);
                        buffer = new byte[(int)f.length()];
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                        bis.read(buffer,0,(int)f.length());

                        socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                        Log.d("BT","RF Connection Created"+socket);
                        //objBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                                try{

                                        objBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                                        socket.connect();
                                        Log.d("BT","Socket Connected = "+socket);

                                        break;
                                }catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                        Log.d("BT","Socket Connection exception = "+e);
                                }
                        }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("BT","Connection NOT OK");
                }

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                os.write(buffer);//,0,buffer.length);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this,"exception "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
}
```

Comment: check this .. http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-simple-spp.html I used it my self and it is working well ..

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the samples provided in the SDK?  If not, you'll find one called "Bluetooth Chat".  It provides the basis for everything you'll need.  I used it some time ago to do what you're trying to do.  Rip out what you don't need and add what you do, and you're off to the races.

I'd provide sample code except I don't have it anymore, sorry.  In any event, you'll find Bluetooth Chat to be a very complete example.

Comment: Yes i tried that one,but when i run the program it shows an edittextbox and button named send.When i type something and press send it shows not connected to a device message.Though it not provide any suggestion for connecting a bluetooth device with my android mobile.Am i miss something?

Comment: Did you pair a device?  You'll need to do that, and it will have to be running a compatible protocol as well (i.e. Bluetooth Chat).  You can pair the device from the Settings menu in the Bluetooth Chat program.